# Flutter: TextEditingController - how to correctly watch for input value changes?

Tags: forms, flutter, input

My first approach was to use `addListener` like its described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). I found one strange and major issue of this approach: Flutter triggers listeners on losing focus. This leads to useless computations of listeners. Am I right? How to be notified **only when value changes**?

Comment: can you add code which you tried?

Comment: It'vy very basic code like here - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#create-a-texteditingcontroller . Listener is triggered when I've got focused input and clicks back button in appBar

Comment: but if you check last demo in same page then it is woking as you expeceted.

Comment: Yep... Looks like it's triggered on focus changes, input position changes, and so on. It's strange that it's not warned in the documentation. From this documentation, it's not expected behaviour

Comment: if you use listener then it will notify you every time data change.

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` widget has a callback method `onChange` which you can use to get value once value is changed. Why would you use controller for that change?

Comment: I need to use `TextEditingController` to be able to control input value... like reset input value

Comment: Yes, and `TextEditingController` is just another property of your `TextField` widget from which you can read current value or apply formatting. But that property is not handling change events, that is part of the `TextField` and its callback `onChange`.

Comment: If you don't like how `addListener` on `TextEditingController`, then supply the callback to `onChange` property of  `TextField`. And you can still supply the `TextEditingController` to do reset value like you want.

Comment: The problem with using both `onChange` and `TextEditingController` I've found is that the `onChange` doesn't get triggered if you edit the field's value using the `TextEditingController`

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextEditingController.addListener` is not best option to detect input value changes because it's triggered on other actions:

- focus looses
- focus position changes

Carefully explore the example on [this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#create-a-texteditingcontroller), change the focus of the fields, check console output, and explore the difference.

Looks like you've got two options:

- Use `TextField.onChange` method to detect changes
- or compare `TextField.text` values on current and previous `TextEditingController.addListener` calls